# Hide 'add to cart' button for some products

Tags: plugins, plugin-development, woocommerce-offtopic

I'm trying to hide the 'add to cart' button for some products (based on the type of product and custom variable `is_customized`).

If the custom variable is_customized is true only then show the 'add to cart' button.

I cannot find a hook using which I can remove/hide the button and then add it again if the `is_customized` is `true`.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know whether my solution is perfect. But it works. Normally if `is_purchasable` is returned to the filter `woocommerce_is_purchasable`, the ‘Add to Cart’ button is displayed, and if `false` is returned the button is hidden.
So, you just need to add the following:

```
add_filter('woocommerce_is_purchasable', 'my_woocommerce_is_purchasable', 10, 2);

function my_woocommerce_is_purchasable($is_purchasable, $product) {
 // Write code to access $is_customized in this function
  return ($is_customized==true ? false : $is_purchasable);
}
```

So in your condition check the value of `is_customized` and pass the value to hook.No incompatibility issues would creep up.